# Calling a web service from a netbeans plugin: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype

Tags: java, swing, web-services, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I'm creating a netbeans plugin (on 7.4) that calls a web service via JAXWS. Unfortunately, when creating the client object (@WebServiceClient), I get the following error message and I'm unsure on how to resolve this.

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:369)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:165)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:125)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
```

So far, I've created a Netbeans Module Suite, containing the following modules
-Apache CXF 2.7.5 with dependencies (error occurs with and without this, no changes)
-Apache jUDDI Client with dependencies (the web service client in question)
-My plugin, which has all the swing and user interface components.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: sadly no, still an open issue

Comment: Any update @spy, Any update on this error?

Comment: no i haven't looked at this problem is ages. the newer nb might be easier to work with. I suspect the problem is related to java SPI

Comment: ok, I have resolved this error as I was getting this on my OSGI setup. this is to do with java version 11, an application upgrade I'm doing. the issue was when the framework initialize at that time it was not able to find the required classes even if the jar was loaded in classpath it was not able to find it. apache-karaf needs the required package information in config.properties with the boot delegation section.